# Taipy read and write functions

Tags: python, function, taipy

I read the user manual, and I just don’t get what `read_fct` and `write_fct` expect for parameters and what format they are supposed to return (for `write_fct`, I don’t even know what to return).

I wrote `read_fct` to send back a list of tuples I pulled from the Data Base, the data I want to look at, and with `write_fct` I don’t know what to do.

Could you please give a little example to explain how it’s supposed to work?

thank you for your help

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of code you can use to understand how it works:

```py
from taipy.config import Config

def read_data(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

def write_data(data, path):
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(path)

generic_data_node_cfg = Config.configure_generic_data_node(id="my_data_node",
                                                         read_fct=read_data,
                                                         write_fct=write_data,
                                                         read_fct_params=["res.csv"],
                                                         write_fct_params=["res.csv"])
```

You also have to be aware of your types. The task function receives the type given by `read_data`. The type returned by the task function should be correct for `write_data` to work.

In other words, this line of code below should work with "foo" and "bar" optional and `function()`, your normal Python function used by your task.

`write_data(function(read_data("foo")), "bar")`

You can also find the documentation [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/core/config/data-node-config/#generic) for more explanation.